# How to retrieve all vertices intersect a Line (CGAL)?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry, cgal

I have a triangle mesh resulted from delaunay triangulation. This mesh has 12 vertices v0, v1, v2,..., v11.

[image]

I want to do vertex query using a single line,

If I define a **line L v0 --> v4**,  how do I retrieve 5 vertices **v0, v1, v2, v3, and v4** efficiently ?

[image]

Other examples:

Line v9 --> v11 : v9, v10, v11

Line v2 --> v10 : v2, v5, v7, v10

Line v1 --> v8  : v1, v8

Line v6 --> v8 : v6, v8

**======== UPDATE ========**

the start and end points of line query are always vertices of the mesh

I found [line_walk](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__2.html#a19a4f322018b6bd16007f4cadbb381de) can return intersected faces but I don't how know to retrieve only the vertices

Answer (score 0):

If those lines are mesh constraints, then you could use [CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Constrained__triangulation__plus__2.html) and more specifically it's member [Context](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/classCGAL_1_1Constrained__triangulation__plus__2.html#a9f5aa4b3a243eaa77ddc42b7620f5bee). That way you can find nodes that are on the specific constraint.

Otherwise, one can perform really naive and expensive operation by constructing [line segment](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Segment__2.html) and then perform [query](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Kernel_23/classCGAL_1_1Segment__2.html#ada92afb0d982c34afaf7c222e670c038) if the point is on segment.

Comment: Sorry, but the lines aren't constraints.